# kubernetes microk8s nodeport not found

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microk8s

i have express app running at docker at http://127.0.0.1:3000/

i am trying to access it from microk8s services from http://127.0.0.1:30002/ but getting not found . here is my deployment file for kubernetes

[image: kubernetes.yaml]

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: simple-node
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      simple: node
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        simple: node
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: simple-node
          image: simple-node:1.0
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: simple-node
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    simple: node
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 30002
```

here is my services and deployment at microk8s .

[image: services]

Comment: You seem to have attached a screen shot of your Kubernetes YAML file, instead of including the actual contents of the file.  Can you replace the image with the YAML file in plain text?  Similarly for your terminal output.

Comment: @DavidMaze edited

Comment: your k8s cluster is not able to access the image  simple-node, please push the image to a registry and then put that image link there.

Comment: here is how you can use the local registry https://microk8s.io/docs/registry-built-in

Answer (score 0):

You have to tag and push image to docker registry. 
The containerd daemon used by MicroK8s is configured to trust this insecure registry. To upload images we have to tag
`simple-node`  before pushing it.

You can install the registry with:

```
microk8s enable registry
```

Execute commands below:

```
$ docker build . 
$ docker tag aaabbccc simple-node:1.0
$ docker push simple-node:1.0
```

Pushing to this insecure registry may fail in some versions of Docker unless the daemon is explicitly configured to trust this registry. To address this you need to edit  `/etc/docker/daemon.json`  and add:

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["localhost:32000"]
}
```

Then restart Docker to load new configuration.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Take a look: [registry-built-in](https://microk8s.io/docs/registry-built-in).